# Is this sentence flawed?

Tags: sentence

I keep trying to make this sentence sound better but I can't figure it out. It's part of an essay I wrote.

"We are threatening ourselves by destroying the plants and animals that we have only recently become cognizant of and the great potential that they may hold in curing the illnesses that have threatened us for centuries."

Comment: It's way too long. If you have a whole essay, why try to pack every idea into one sentence?

Comment: *(Cognizant) of* has two objects, on opposite sides, only one of which is connected to it with relative *that*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure other answers will focus on specifics of grammar and syntax. But it's worth looking at the wider context of your question.

This sentence is inelegant but sound. Style is pervasive in a piece of work, and isolated attempts to resuscitate individual sentences will only make them look garish and tarty. But it is definitely worthwhile us examining some from time-to-time, so that we can work on our style.

Try extracting the individual parts of your sentence and expressing them separately. Then take a good look at them, polish them, arrange them, and join them back together. Thoughts come from our mouths like hairballs do from cats and so this takes some skill.

You might not like what any one of us suggests you do to your sentence, but if you follow the procedure above, in time you will start to find a voice.

Imitation is a good starting point. Listen to the patterns of people's voices and text. For example, you might like the styles of Clinton and Obama (I do), or comedians or newspaper columnists. Just take care you are appropriate to the context of your work.

I might have written

> Regularly, we learn of plants and animals which hold some key to the treatment of disease. And yet we continue to drive many to the brink of extinction. In doing so, we also endanger ourselves.

but make no great claims from doing so.

(Everything is flawed and impermanent. Don't beat yourself up over it).

Comment: You are a brilliant writer.

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatically correct, but rather breathless. Try introducing a pause, to offer the reader some relief:

"...cognizant of, as well as the great potential..."

You might also consider turning it into two sentences:

"...cognizant of. We are also destroying the great potential..."

Answer (score 1):

Recently discovered animals and plants hold great potential in curing some of the illnesses that have threatened us for centuries. We are threatening ourselves by destroying them.